# How to send binary content image plus text with it for a share button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to develop a share button, that takes a screenshot of the application and a Hashtag text with it, so far, Have managed to only share the Image, I cant seem to be able to add text next to the Image. Here is my code

```
    AppExecutors.mainThread.execute {
            val url = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    view.getViewContext(),
                    view.getViewContext().applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                    imageFile)
            val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, url)
                type = "image/jpeg"
            }
            view.getViewActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to include `EXTRA_TEXT` along with `EXTRA_STREAM`, where `EXTRA_TEXT` is your text. However, bear in mind that an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` is only supposed to have one of those two extras, so not every app will apply both the image and the text.